# Calling a method on an Optional Double to convert to String

Tags: swift, extension-methods, option-type

I've written this in order to easily format floating point numbers as strings with various levels of precision.

```
extension FloatingPoint {
    func str(_ precision: Int) -> String {
        return String(format: "%."+String(precision)+"f", self as! CVarArg)
    }
}
```

It works great for non-optional variables with floating point types:

```
var myDouble: Double = 3.1415
var text = myDouble.str(2) // sets text = "3.14"
```

Is there a way of getting something like this to work for an optional `Double`?

```
var myNilDouble: Double? = nil
var text = myNilDouble.str(2) // I'd like it to set text = ""
```

I'd like the implementation to support `nil` and non-`nil` conversion to string.

Comment: `var text = myNilDouble.map { $0.str(2) } ?? ""`. Anyway, you are trying to make your code shorter while you should make it more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not calling the method on a `Double`, you're calling it on an `Optional<Double>`; completely different type. So you need the method to exist on `Optional`:

```
extension Optional where Wrapped : FloatingPoint {
    func string(usingPrecision precision: Int) -> String {
        guard let double = self else { return "" }
        return double.str(precision)
    }
}
```

I don't like this interface, though; I don't think it's `Optional`'s job to decide to emit an empty string. Instead I would suggest an initializer on `String` itself that takes an `Optional` floating point:

```
import Foundation

extension String {
    init<N : FloatingPoint>(_ value: N?, precision: Int) {
        guard let value = value else { self.init(); return }
        self.init(format: "%.\(precision)f", value as! CVarArg)
    }
}
```

Now you write

```
let value: Double? = nil
let text = String(value, precision: 2)    // ""
```

Another option is a free function, again taking an `Optional`. (You can also of course make it the caller's choice as to what `nil` resolves to, as Sulthan said.)

Comment: Unrelated to the concrete question, but I wonder if `as! CVarArg` would succeed for arbitrary FloatingPoint types.

Comment: Good point, I was worried about that as well, @MartinR. I _think_ that it works for any so-called "trivial" type, though.

Comment: I am not sure about that. CVarArg conformance is declared in [VarArgs.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/VarArgs.swift) for certain types, together with the corresponding alignments and necessary promotions (such as `float` to `double`). Declaring conformance for additional types it not supported.

Comment: With the (stricter, but perhaps sufficiently general) `<N : BinaryFloatingPoint>` one could simply do `Double(value)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to use optional chaining and nil coalescing:

```
var text = myNilDouble?.str(2) ?? ""
```

Although you might end up with many repetitions of this pattern, the advantage is that you have better control over the nil scenario, maybe in some situations you'll want to use `"(null)"` as default value.